# Resolving interfaces at runtime (just before the usage)

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Lets say i have the following interface

```
interface ILeague
{
    string ShowSquad();
}
```

Following classes implementing them

```
class EPL : ILeague
{
    public string ShowSquad()
    {
      return "EPL players collection";
    }
} 

class LaLiga: ILeague
{
  public string ShowSquad()
  {
     return "La-liga player Collection";
  }
}
```

i am consuming this interface as shown below

```
public string ShowLeaguePlayers(ILeague leagueDataProvider)
{
   return leagueDataProvider.ShowSquad();
}
```

Now , depending on the league i am in , i want to show different data. Sometimes EPL and other times LaLiag.  This switch can happen with in the same execution cycle.
I tried the following approach

```
class LeagueDataProvider : ILeague
{
    private ILeague m_Provider;

    private string league;
    private void SetContext()
    {
        // Have some logic to figure out the league
        league = "EPL";

        if (league.Equals("EPL"))
        {
            m_Provider = new EPL();
        }
        else
        {
            m_Provider = new LaLiga();
        }
    }

    public string ShowSquad()
    {
        SetContext();
        return m_Provider.ShowSquad();
    }
}
```

I have modified my client code to below

```
void ShowData()
{
   ILeague Dataprovider = new LeagueDataProvider();
   Console.WriteLine(ShowLeaguePlayers(Dataprovider));             
}
 
// copied again for easy viewing
public string ShowLeaguePlayers(ILeague leagueDataProvider)
{
   return leagueDataProvider.ShowSquad();
}
```

This works fine , but every time i make a call to ShowSquad , it has to check for the league and fetch the data. Is there a better way to do this ?

What i am trying to achieve here :

Depending on the league , i want to get different data when i call ShowSquad .
I should be able to mock ILeague in UT and in future there might be many more implementations of ILeague so i want to avoid modifying and re-testing components which consume them

Comment: Yes, its hard to know why you designed it like this, what concerns you were separating, and what you were trying to achieve. Its likely you'd want your `LeagueDataProvider` as a generic class. though its hard to tell

Comment: I should be able to mock ILeague in my UT. This is main reason i am refactoring this code. And other reason being ,there might be many more implementations of ILeague in future, So i want to avoid modifying the classes which consume them in future

Comment: I wouldn't make `LeagueDataProvider` an `ILeague` because it isn't. It's more-or-less a factory of sorts. You want it to contain or produce an `ILeague`, not implement one. Google "c# class factory pattern example"

Comment: @Andy That was my initial thought, make LeagueDataProvider as a factory  which returns  a ILeague which i can use . 
But to write UT ,i should make my factory implement an interface and mock that in my UT. I was not so sure if its good practice for a factory should implement an interface

Comment: You could make it implement an interface. Like `public interface ILeagueFactory { ILeague CreateLeague(); }`

Comment: @Andy yeah. But even now i have to check for League Type in every call . I want to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with the factory pattern :
Interfaces:

```
interface ILeague
{
    string ShowSquad();
}

interface ILeagueFactory
{
  ILeague CreateLeague();
}
```

implementations:

```
class EPL : ILeague
{
    public string ShowSquad()
    {
      return "EPL players collection";
    }
} 

class LaLiga: ILeague
{
  public string ShowSquad()
  {
    return "La-liga player Collection";
  }
}

class EPLFactory : ILeagueFactory
{
  public ILeague CreateLeague()
  {
    return new EPL();
  }
}

class LaLigaFactory : ILeagueFactory
{
  public ILeague CreateLeague()
  {
    return new LaLiga();
  }
}
```

To fetch rigth league factory, you can wrap the factories you need in a collection :

```
class LeagueFactoryCollection
{
  private IDictionary<string, ILeagueFactory> factories;

  public LeagueFactoryCollection()
  {
    factories = new Dictionary<string, ILeagueFactory>();
  }

  public void Add(string key, ILeagueFactory factory)
  {
    factories.Add(key, factory);
  }

  public ILeagueFactory Get(string key)
  {
    return factories[key];
  }
}
```

Now you should be able to add new League types easier:

```
//define your needed factories
var leagueCollections = new LeagueFactoryCollection();
leagueCollections.Add("EPL", new EPLFactory());
leagueCollections.Add("LaLiga", new LaLigaFactory());

//consumer
leagueCollections.Get("EPL").CreateLeague().ShowSquad();
```

Your consumer will not change when you'll add new league